# How do I test my Octree implementation?

Tags: octree

I decided to use an Octree subdivision in my game. After implementing it, I do some research (a few tests and comparisons) and came up with several questions about.

**The main question:**
**How to test my Octree implementation?**
Are there some points that I must note while coding an octree? Is it possible to decide how my code works (good or not enough good) without actual game? Or it would be better if I test the Octree in real situation? Is it right to compare my C++ Octree with Octree implementation for other engines (as example I found C# one for Unity)?

Comment: I've removed your two sub-questions since they're unrelated and worth going into in depth on their own. Please [ask them separately](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Take an octree implementation you know works and check if the 2 returns the same thing

Comment: @Bálint How to test working speed then? Unity itself can dramaticly reduce working speed of C# octree, for example

Comment: @Green working speed is relative, try measuring the computational time, and only start fixing it, if it's too much

Comment: @Bálint the computational time highly depends on some implementation specific features (c++ templates is good illustration). And the computational time of what? Whole application or just the part with octree? Is there some others things that I must note?

Comment: I would suggest trying it in both scenes where octrees work well and those where they dont. As for the scenes you could try find papers that do similar comparisons - they usually conclude how bad scenes look like(and which are fine). Also, comparing to an implementation in other language *and* whole different settings(Unity is not just octree, it is whole engine with bunch of things running in background) will not give much of meaningful results. Testing software is *very* complex topic, much more than the implementation itself.

Comment: @wondra honestly, I hope that someone has some test cases for the octree and say a few words about his implementation, these allow me make a decision about my code. But you wrote right, there are papers that can contain the test cases and other useful stuff for me. Thank you for the comment.